# Callbacks inside a loop : how can i use parameter of loop in callback?

Tags: android, loops, callback

In a loop, I need to call multiple times a method with callback. How can i use parameter parsedObject in onObjectChecked() ?

```
@Override
public void onObjectsMustBeParsed(String parsableObjects) {
    String[] parsedObjects = parsableObjects.split(",");

    for (String parsedObject : parsedObjects){

        checkObject(parsedObject, new CheckObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onObjectChecked() {
                //Object check

                // here call method with parameters : parsedObject
                // Example : transformObject(parsedObject);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                // Object not checked

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note : When I don't have a loop, I use a final variable. I don't know if it's a good practice ! Please tell me if it is !

Comment: What do you mean with 'the incremental value of loop'?

Comment: @greenapps I edit question but i don't find the good word to explain. I want the value of "parsedObject" inside the callback "onObjectChecked()"

Comment: It's fine (and actually good practice) to use a final variable any time you have an object that you don't need/want edited.

Comment: @Shadesblade Good, but not possible with a loop

Comment: `How can I get the"for-each" value of loop in callback ?`. The question is wrong. `checkObject(parsedObject,....`. How can i use parameter `parsedObject` in `onObjectChecked()`. For that you have to go inside `checkObject()` function.

Comment: @greenapps edited ! Go inside checkObject() function is the only solution ? In real case, I use multiple nested callback, and they are also used in other contexts that have ever need this variable . If I can avoid returning the expected variable across all callbacks, it's better

Comment: @greenapps Android Studio suggest me that : `for (final Product product : products) {` That's correct ? Here, it's not a String but an Object

Comment: Well did you try? I do not know these functions. What there should be moreover is the ssme parsmeter for onObjectchecked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over this part of the code you should instead change your architecture and have the `parsedObject` supplied as parameter to `onObjectChecked()`.

But to have only a few changes to your current code you could just implement a simple inner class (not anonymous) holding the `parsedObject`.

```
@Override
public void onObjectsMustBeParsed(String parsableObjects) {
    String[] parsedObjects = parsableObjects.split(",");

    MyCheckObjectCallback callback = new MyCheckObjectCallback();

    for (String parsedObject : parsedObjects) {
        callback.parsedObject = parsedObject;
        checkObject(parsedObject, callback);
    }
}

private class MyCheckObjectCallback implements CheckObjectCallback {

    String parsedObject = null;

    @Override
    public void onObjectChecked() {
        // Object check
        // here call method with parameters : parsedObject
        // Example : transformObject(parsedObject);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        // Object not checked
    }
}
```